# MVC 5: Controller gets ignored

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm sure the question is as stupid as simple, but since nobody can give me a hint, I give it a try: I'm learning MVC Asp.Net by creating a small company-internal application, which has only 1 Page.

I worked trough the Tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started, which helps me a lot.

My problem itself: I went to the Controllers-Folder, added a Controller by selecting "MVC 5 Controller with read/write actions", then in the Views-Subfolder Views\NewItem\ I added a Index.cshtml by selecting "Empty Page".

But now when I debug the Program and select in the URL it keeps shooting a 404-error, meaning the Page is not found. I debugged the Controller, but it doesn't even goes to the Index-Method.

Is there anything I'm missing. I guess it's so stupid and clear I dont even find it on the Internet.

Nevertheless thanks in advance for all answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easy way to add a View for your action method that is placed inside the controller you're working at, is to right click inside the body of your action method (that you want the users to access from the browser) and add the View you want, and the MVC automatically will add the View in the right place inside the View folder in Solution Explorer.

Comment: Hum, I'm not sure if this did the Trick or the Restart of the PC. If I use your Way, does it anything special we can't do manually? I dont see any special properties nor a difference.

Comment: No, it does not anything special. Sometimes it happens with me too, I just added a View file to the View folder but not inside the subfolder (with the name of my controller I work with)...and causes me problems and ...bad words :) .

Comment: Well, in future I will use this Function, so this won't happen again. Thanks so far.

Answer (score 1):

Please check you RouteConfig for rout configuration

Comment: I have just the Standard-Route there:

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }

I hope I dont have to route every new Controller by itself, since the Standard-Controllers like AccountController or HomeController work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your controller is correctly named - e.g. NewItemController.  If it doesn't have the Controller suffix, it won't be picked up.

It should also have an action method matching your view name, e.g. `public ActionResult Index()` in this case.

Comment: The Controller's Name: SimpleSalesOrderController.cs 
I used the URL the GET-Methods shows in the Comment. The URL in the View is: ~/SimpleSalesOrder/Index. In the Controller I got:
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

But if i set a Debug-Point, it doesn't show up.